# $dirty not changing after changing the respective ng-model value in js code

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I want to know why the $dirty of the respective select elem is not changed when we change the ng-model value of it in js.

It's very basic (http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2859/)

```
//HTML
<select name="mySelect" ng-model="value" ng-options="item for item in data"></select>

//JS
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.value = "1";
    $scope.data = ["1", "2"];

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.value = "2";
    }, 3000);    
}
```

Is this an angular bug? or $dirty is not suppose to be set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular takes care of setting an input to $dirty for you when you change input's value manually.

To do it programmatically, use [`$setDirty();`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

You might also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071648/angular-js-programmatically-setting-a-form-field-to-dirty) useful.