# How to explicitly set a text box in a form to dirty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I already saw questions like, [How to set a particular field in a form to dirty in angularjs 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222150/how-to-set-a-particular-field-in-a-form-to-dirty-in-angularjs-1-3) and [Angular.js programmatically setting a form field to dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071648/angular-js-programmatically-setting-a-form-field-to-dirty) but they are not working.

I am auto-filling a text box in angularjs as:

`$scope.address.city =  "Santa Clara";`

`$scope.address.city.$dirty =  true;`

And in the html I have `ng-model="address.city" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur' }"`.

However, `$scope.address.city.$dirty =  true;` is giving **undefined** in the console.

I have used

`$http.get("somewebsite.com").success(function(data){  $timeout(function () {
              $scope.address.city.$dirty =  true;
          }, 0);
          console.log('$scope.address.city.$dirty',$scope.address.city.$dirty);})`

but still I am getting error as `TypeError: Cannot set property '$dirty' of undefined`

I am using angular 1.3.1 .

Answer (score 1):

In Html,

```
<form name="formName">
    <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="address.city" 
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur' }" />
</form>
```

In controller,

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.formName.city.$dirty = true;
}, 0);
```

note that `name` attributes are used not the model names.

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1KBuOv4lWVtC127UDzo2?p=preview)

Comment: your code will always work because you are using angular 1.2, `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur' }"` supported in 1.3+

Comment: problem is not about `ng-model-options` should work in 1.3 also http://plnkr.co/edit/2qbHmf2CyGjFP9FMIJ1R?p=preview

Comment: i have used `$http.get("website.com").success(function(data){ and inside this I have to make the text box dirty. I have kept timeout function here})`but still I am getting error as `TypeError: Cannot set property '$dirty' of undefined`

Comment: are u sure ur using the `names` in the `form` and the `input` ?

Comment: @K.Toress see my answer..and this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Q60gcwO5zjq2Hu1g1GJA?p=preview..he is overriding address variable from ajax call which was already associated with form

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed `name` attribute on either `form` or `field`. You form name should be `address` & field name should be `city` then only you can access `$scope.address.city.$dirty` in controller scope or UI

**Markup**

```
<form name="address">
    <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="address.city" 
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur' }" />
</form>
```

It could use on html as `address.city.$dirty` & inside controller it would be `$scope.address.city.$dirty`

**Update**

In your case form name `address` scope is conflicting with your `address`, you are overriding the `address` scope variable which already contains form object. So after overriding it all the form property gets erased. See my plunkr in which I reproduced your issue exactly what I'm doing there.

[**Plunkr with Issue**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q60gcwO5zjq2Hu1g1GJA?p=preview)

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="address.city" 
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur' }" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.form.city.$dirty = true;
}, 0);
```

[**Fixed plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdaktVVqznpW8imlMykU?p=preview).

Comment: I haven't missed it. The form name is address and the name of the text is city. :( still $scope.address.city.$dirty is giving undefined.

Comment: ohh.sorry that my bad..your form name is conflicting with your scope variable `address` you need to change your form name

Comment: as far I know, the problem is not in naming. I have added few more details in the question.

Comment: @Tehreem do look at my edit..both the plunkr..`address.city` is converted to object because you have added $dirty property to it..when they have same name of `address` as form name & `address` as scope variable name

Comment: @Tehreem did you looked at my answer?